# Chow to count of 1/10 of a second

Tags: c#, timer, unity-game-engine

I am trying to figure out how to count 10 times each second and display it.

I have an int called countpoints which is what the user starts with points. Lets say 800.

I would like to drop 10 points each second but showing each point falling instead of every 10 points like my script below does.

here is how I have done so far:

```
if(miliseconds <= 0){

    if(seconds <= 0){
        minutes--;
        seconds = 59;
    }
    else if(seconds >= 0){
        seconds--;
        countpoints = countpoints-10;

    }

    miliseconds = 100;

}

miliseconds -= Time.deltaTime * 100;
```

This runs in void update and here countpoints falls by 10 each second. but i would like to be able to show the numbers drop down like a stopwatch each second. How do i do that?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: there would be more help if u could just show update with parameters, there is some timer object from unity?

Answer (score 0):

You should use coroutine for that calculation instead of in Update(). It can be very easy with the coroutine. You just need to start croutine and then wait for 0.1 seconds and decrease counterpoints by 1. Again call that coroutine inside that to keep it running. Just add condition whenever you want to keep on calling it.

```
private int countpoints=800;
private float t=0.1f;
private int noOfSeconds=90;
private int min;
private int sec;
private int temp=0;

void Start () 
{
    StartCoroutine(StartTimer());
}

IEnumerator StartTimer ()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(t);
    countpoints--;
    temp++;
    if(temp==10)
    {
        temp=0;
        noOfSeconds--;
    }
    min = noOfSeconds/60;
    sec = noOfSeconds%60;

    if(noOfSeconds>0)
    {
        StartCoroutine(StartTimer());
    }
}

void OnGUI () 
{
    GUI.Label(new Rect(100f,100f,100f,50f),countpoints.ToString());
    GUI.Label(new Rect(100f,160f,100f,50f),"Time : "+min.ToString("00")+":"+sec.ToString("00"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do it in the Update method and decrement the points once every 100ms, you need to take care of not rounding things up or down as the error would be systematic and you'll get choppy results.

Using coroutines won't work as expected as the interval is not guaranteed.

```
private float _milliseconds = 0;
private int points = 800;

void Update()
{
  _milliseconds += Time.delta * 1000;

  if( _milliseconds > 100 )
  {
   points--;
   //add updating GUI code here for points
   _milliseconds -= 100;
  }
}
```

You won't get choppy decrements as the _milliseconds are decremented by 100, so even if there are differences in the duration of the frames in the long run you'll get a proper handling.

One problem with the script is if frames take a lot more than 100ms consistenly , but if it takes that long you probably have bigger problems:D